# How do you change the value of an HTML element with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this: `<input type="button" value="hello">` I want to change the `value` with javascript so that it is `value="goodbye"`. How do I do this?

Following @David's advice in the comments below here is the code I tried but could not get to work before posting this question:

```
var createBttn = document.getElementById('create');
createBttn.innerHTML = 'value="goodbye"';
```

Comment: Why was this question voted down twice? I am a beginner :(

Comment: @chromedude, **agreed**. +1 (to your comment *and* question).

Comment: @chromedude: no worries, I neutralize the downvotes with my +1 :)

Comment: @Michael Mao, that means I raised the score to +1 with **my** (near-simultaneous) +1! =D Ah, the benevolence! =)

Comment: @chromedude: I guess the other guys may want you to show what you've done, so we can understand your situation better.

Comment: @Michael Mao, then, to be fair, they *should have said so* this whole random drive-by down-voting thing is... **very**, **very** irritating sometimes. =/

Comment: @Michael ok, I don't really see the need

Comment: @chromedude.  I think these posts explain it:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38595/sympathy-upvote-problem-on-questions-closed

Comment: @YWE, I'm not sure. I don't think that this question is unhelpful, or bad. It's concise and brief, sure, and it could definitely be improved if @chromedude had tried to research this himself before asking (and documented that research, the 'what-I've-tried-that-didn't-work' part), but it doesn't seem to merit the down-votes. I up-voted to counter what I felt were undeserved down-votes, rather than simply sympathy-up-voting. This might not have happened if the down-voters had **explained** their down-vote, though.

Comment: @David Thomas, sorry about that I guess I should have told what I had tried, but had found fail. I had tried `var createBttn = document.getElementById('create'); createBttn.innerHTML = 'value="goodbye"';`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to get a reference to the object that you want to change the value on, then assign the `value` property of that element, like this:

Say your element had an `id` of "someButton":

```
var btn = document.getElementById('someButton');
btn.value = 'goodbye';
```

Comment: @chromedude, You should tick this answer as the accepted answer then. :)

Comment: sorry about that one. I had to wait 15mins to accept it and by then I had left my computer and forgot about it.